# DB2 timestamp comparison

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have the following table with 4 rows only:
[image]

When i run the query

```
 select * from TABLE9 
     where dateLastChanged < dateLastUploaded
```

on this table, i expect to see the rows 1 & 4, however i get this:
[image]

When i run

```
 select * from TABLE9 
     where dateLastChanged > dateLastUploaded
```

i get 
[image]

, and to

```
 select * from TABLE9 
     where dateLastChanged <> dateLastUploaded
```

i get all 4 of it. `... where dateLastChanged = dateLastUploaded` gets none.

I tried casting to timestamp-- got the same results:

```
 select * from TABLE9 
     where timestamp(dateLastChanged) < timestamp(dateLastUploaded)
```

Whats missing???

my first time with DB2 on a prj. increasingly "loving" it.

Note: I'm aware that i can get around this on the Java side.

//--------------------------

**EDIT:**

clarifying what i thought was clear in the Q:

How come

```
 select * from TABLE9 
     where dateLastChanged < dateLastUploaded
```

is returning `dateLastChanged < dateLastUploaded`, `dateLastChanged > dateLastUploaded` and `dateLastChanged = dateLastUploaded`.

How does DB2 decide which timestamp is greater, smaller, equal, not equal to one another. the timestamps for row `tNumber=bbbbb` were created and written at the same time.

//--------------------

**EDIT-2**

In my original Q - "greater-than/less-than" in the comparison of the timestamps is confused. This (the latter timestamp is greater/not) 
is easy enough to figure once i get passed the **inconsistency** i laid out in the Q and the edit right before this.

Comment: Care to explain why you think that '17:24' is less (that is, earlier) than '17:14'?

Comment: Have you ever looked at your timestamps? Just look close enough and you will find all your answers. Everythings works like expected!

Comment: I am also LOVING DB2 because it is correct.

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher well- hope not "Everythings works like expected!". Read the edit.

Comment: Ok once more - let us look at your first example. You say that you expect row 1 to get returned - which is TNUMBER=400124. Looking at your timestamps for that row both have the same date so youhave to look at the time and 17:24 > 17:14. So this is the reason why it is NOT returned. Your expectation is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher well - how then do you explain tNumber=ccccc appearing in the query up there while tNumber=400124 isn't. (re-)read the edit(s). **carefully**.

Comment: Sorry your edit is confusing in my eyes. If you refer to your first example and  tNumber=ccccc the 2016-08-13 is greater than 2016-08-03 - just looking at the date is enough.

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher i guess i should develop some faith in DB2. been biased from those earlier stuff and blaming it on just about anything. thanks for clarification.

Comment: @user6401178 yes trust DB2 and trust in answers you get here :-) and don't forget to flag answers and vote for good comments.

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher DB2 still shouldn't be "discreditted" though. the one on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729620/db2-version-lower-version-on-scrapbook stands still. i took up Data Studio just out of that. hit that odd query-terminator vs statemtn-terminator problem of DS. burnt time till i figured the editor isn't just an editor but also the 1st phase of executing a query. these are all glorious. keeping faith though.

Answer (score 1):

DB2 uses ISO-defined logic to compare timestamps. It means that for "lower" the earlier date/time is taken, for "greater" the later date/time. For your example DB2 has evaluated everything correctly. To get different results you need to change the values... :)

Answer (score 0):

in similar context I found out that problem was missing ; at the end of the command.
current DB tools need to select part or full selection of command text to execute if ; missing, because without such selection it takes previous line in SQL editor as part of command on current line and it leads often to executing 2 selects at once, which is syntax error without command delimiter...